# insert a CR character in a file using shell script

Tags: string, bash, shell, file, unix

i have a huge single block of data which i want to split into lines by inserting a Carriage Return before some identified patterns.
(at this stage, i don't want to use the linux split command).

So I am looking at :

1. how to identify the pattern in the data block
2. how to insert the CR right before the pattern starting position.

Example:

the block is `1234abcde56785abcde53453FEFDabcde`

the result should look like this inside the file:

```
1234
abcde56785
abcde53453FEFD
abcde
```

thanks community !

Comment: What are your rules for this splitting?

Comment: when you say carriage return you are talking about a Linux EOL `\n`? no need for windows `\r\n` EOL right?

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern was not easy to understand at all so next time please try to add some information:

You can use the following `sed` command:

```
echo "1234abcde5678abcde53453FEFDabcde" | sed -E 's/(abcde[0-9]*[A-Z]*)/\n\1/g'                                                
1234
abcde5678
abcde53453FEFD
abcde
```

If you need to have windows EOL then change it into

```
sed -E 's/(abcde[0-9]*[A-Z]*)/\r\n\1/g'
```

For explanations about `sed`:

- `-E` is for extended regex support otherwise you need to escape characters such as `(,),+,{,}`
- `s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/g` command to find and replace in global mode

For explanations about the regex:

[**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/QB8keQ/1)

- `()` for grouping and backreference
- `abcde[0-9]*[A-Z]*` in order to match everything that starts with `abcde` then eventually some digits and eventually some uppercase letters:

Regex starting point: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html

Answer (score 1):

Not sure completely about your requirement based on your shown output, could you please try following and let me know if this helps.

```
awk '{gsub(/abcde/,"\n&")} 1' Input_file
```

OR(in case of `abcde` string is not going to be always the same and it could be any small letter word)

```
awk '{gsub(/[a-z]+/,"\n&")} 1'  Input_file
```

Comment: spot on ! tbanks !

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: Nice Answer as usual!